# Оптимизация select mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы. **data, modemsInfo, dataResponse.**
**data** - вся дежурная ежеминутная информация с модемов +100строк/мин(~1.5млн всего пока),
**modemsInfo** - информация о модемах, кому принадлежит итд(сейчас ~10шт. более 3000шт не планируется),
 **dataResponse** - ответы модемов. По сути тоже самое что **data** но мало строк(пока ~10)

 Раз в 5 сек собираю последнюю информацию по всем модемам владельца (далее в коде *idCompany*). В определенный момент время запроса занимало **6**с и чем больше становилось модемов, которые не передавали еще никакой информации **data** и **dataResponse**, тем страшней становилось время выборки. **+1**с за один свежий модем. Ковырял, оптимизировал используя различные статьи и ответы. Стало **1.4**с. Чуть полегче, но мне кажется это очень долго. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кому не лень в этом ковыряться, что еще можно сделать?
Завязаны между собой через **serialNum** и **typeReceipt**  тоже самое что и ** modeDialog**
Наполнение таблицы **data**:

```
INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227124, '9faec1317eb285f9f20254b6d2e20670', 111111111111, 0, 83206, 76105, 10553, 25226, 80, 0, 411, 74, 22, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 0, '2023-12-17 14:00:10');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227122, '931a1e61b06b2fbcbdea07f6d8fe59ed', 111111111111, 0, 12809, 99159, 42986, 1461, 75, 0, 575, 838, 42, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 0, '2023-12-17 14:00:10');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227121, '393fd8d56d1338b6e5742a95bdd17a58', 822917000001, 0, 24478, 14257, 73864, 43259, 34, 31, 673, 936, 45, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 0, '2023-12-17 14:00:10');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227120, '6592908f518c9b43c0dfc6bcc798bfbd', 111111111111, 0, 55502, 40960, 80864, 26944, 81, 63, 876, 152, 80, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 0, '2023-12-17 14:00:10');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227119, 'b3f8f973c5f3ccabfc5f58be74249c9b', 822125000000, 0, 18944, 89632, 75158, 46181, 58, 87, 812, 368, 65, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:10');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227118, '08d986357608dd939184cfbdc1041a81', 822125000000, 0, 13852, 61660, 99013, 51948, 77, 78, 848, 558, 35, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:10');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227117, 'eaf4a664592b29aba94f5aefe4519c6e', 822917000001, 0, 19293, 14457, 81638, 5465, 26, 3, 818, 951, 95, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:10');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227116, 'e54394b113c5d91c77eb068772c234e7', 822917000001, 0, 56479, 56457, 32901, 75286, 69, 75, 456, 205, 38, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:09');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227115, 'a410df8e915d78d4e65020e16a9061e7', 111111111111, 0, 25941, 33667, 78140, 83016, 36, 83, 67, 314, 14, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:09');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227111, '43a8f3d4dbcf7af684d7ec31183f7c2c', 111111111111, 0, 28033, 69911, 41437, 97644, 20, 42, 742, 384, 88, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:09');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227110, '1e084b1a8028754ef6a6a6113f686638', 822917000001, 0, 58290, 28145, 8922, 54037, 12, 53, 135, 951, 29, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:09');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227109, 'bd5ab82e1aee708f560805983724568e', 822125000000, 0, 70906, 3568, 53202, 41062, 28, 28, 914, 527, 53, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:09');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227108, 'ea2247e979a8062840c650c0f5254036', 111111111111, 0, 81361, 46912, 87251, 11789, 9, 89, 452, 971, 75, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:09');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227104, '9642c393186c731193c51828490d76d3', 111111111111, 0, 94653, 222, 37479, 78288, 78, 89, 134, 96, 79, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227103, '7d5780e49716d92c33c2e6f500021026', 111111111111, 0, 76185, 85751, 46847, 66784, 97, 66, 725, 19, 59, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227102, 'dac779c303bcf599174685a4d629b657', 822125000000, 0, 8978, 23016, 82799, 36104, 66, 64, 550, 817, 26, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227101, 'f0db8b14b9357a5d0db62110939994e3', 822125000000, 0, 39960, 69244, 26330, 24935, 38, 43, 197, 554, 13, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227100, '8c9712df7f264efeb934753d64cbe232', 822917000001, 0, 78323, 9031, 9834, 23217, 94, 45, 461, 856, 58, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227099, '05c9d72b9f7dc9995c1c5d2981b1fb9d', 822125000000, 0, 25667, 74187, 25871, 42459, 59, 83, 858, 455, 45, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227098, 'adb125ba523e789c43b280bf23572ac4', 822917000001, 0, 42359, 72061, 36836, 29225, 40, 68, 677, 695, 40, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227097, 'f6c062d3b84362ec93a509a44f199f0f', 111111111111, 0, 40311, 80755, 36442, 33862, 6, 44, 452, 746, 52, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227096, '8b4c70bb37860e457170c7d57eb64b99', 822125000000, 0, 6601, 98527, 1455, 11081, 30, 57, 986, 818, 89, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227095, 'b6eef858ec15886c113510c970f64e23', 822917000001, 0, 99418, 31939, 52525, 90310, 80, 40, 970, 955, 20, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:08');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227090, 'b8c3812632b8582d874a2e89546e07d7', 822917000001, 0, 64064, 40638, 17418, 24982, 77, 30, 541, 585, 38, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:07');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227089, '26532d9cb67ded61bad390675ea4f552', 822917000001, 0, 22571, 41643, 52396, 62944, 54, 73, 448, 93, 22, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:07');


INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227082, '268405297d3e3fcccb2a17c0d3173dd0', 111111111111, 0, 73953, 44671, 71077, 64229, 39, 23, 358, 474, 83, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:07');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227081, '405d9b0bf00bd68fa256b094843dcee6', 111111111111, 0, 63800, 68218, 58017, 81928, 17, 79, 919, 195, 45, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:07');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227080, '81786eb3a525e88f8251e760f2bdaa0b', 822125000000, 0, 39770, 10714, 39325, 61061, 62, 69, 656, 316, 91, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:07');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227079, '8893945f6a00932f278011122e44558b', 822917000001, 0, 90452, 70936, 44922, 51558, 55, 95, 63, 50, 98, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:07');

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.data (id, md5receipt, serialNum, mode, Ub, Ib, Up, IL, Ta, Tc, tL, tN, PL, Hand, Fire, Night, `Load`, Disch, OverIL, ShortL, ip, typeReceipt, timeReceipt) VALUES (1227078, 'b8f9b8c17c51ef0dca852868b144a67b', 111111111111, 0, 22306, 56306, 26453, 36391, 63, 32, 623, 93, 90, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1370562830, 1, '2023-12-17 14:00:07');
```

Наполнение таблицы **dataResponse**:

```
INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('1', null, '822917000001', 11212, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('2', null, '822917000000', 1212, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('3', null, '822917000001', null, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('4', null, '822125000000', 11313, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('5', null, '822125000000', 4114, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('6', null, '822917000001', 1212, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('9', null, '822917000001', 1212, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('10', null, '822917000001', null, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('11', null, '822917000001', 1212, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('12', null, '822917000001', 241515, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('13', null, '822917000000', 1535132, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('14', null, '822917000001', 4361, '2', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('15', null, '822125000000', 346, '1', null, null);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.dataResponse (md5receipt, serialNum, text, ip, commandResponse, timeReceipt,
                                          typeReceipt)
VALUES ('16', null, '822125000000', 13464, '2', null, null);
```

Наполнение таблицы **modemsInfo**:

```
INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (21, 822917000001, 1, '1', '79803400001', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 16:02:58',
    '2023-12-17 16:02:58', 0, 0, 0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 000001);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (22, 822125000000, 1, '2', '79803400000', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 16:04:08',
    '2023-12-17 16:04:08', 0, 0, 0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 000000);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (44, 111111111111, 1, '3', '79802410000', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 21:21:57',
    '2023-12-17 21:20:37', 0, 0, 0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 111111);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (45, null, 1, '4', '71112111111', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 22:16:13', 0, 0,
    0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 112211);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (46, null, 1, '5', '73333333333', 0, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 22:16:39', 0, 0,
    0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 333333);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (47, null, 3, '6', '71333333333', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 22:16:57', 0, 0,
    0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 121312);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (49, null, 1, '8', '73332223333', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 22:17:50', 16, 0,
    0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 212211);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (50, null, 4, '9', '79802412222', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 22:18:14', 17, 0,
    0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 112312);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (51, null, 1, '10', '71231231331', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 22:18:29', 24,
    0, 0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 312312);

INSERT INTO u2378356_ledMonitor.modemsInfo (id, serialNum, idCompany, nameModem, phoneNumber, modeDialog,
                                        commandStatusGPRS, region, city, street, structure, latitude, longitude,
                                        timeActivation, timeRegister, idGroup, idIcon, model, keyDelete,
                                        endTimeKeyDelete, commandStatusSMS, billingPeriodDay, billingPeriodTime,
                                        identifySerialNum)
VALUES (52, null, 1, '11', '71231333331', 1, '?', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '2023-12-17 22:18:50', 0, 0,
    0, null, null, '?', '01', '00:00:00', 123123);
```

Результат выборки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблицы:

```
 create table if not exists data
(
id          bigint unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
md5receipt  char(32)                            not null,
serialNum   bigint unsigned                     not null,
mode        tinyint unsigned                    not null,
Ub          mediumint unsigned                  not null,
Ib          mediumint unsigned                  not null,
Up          mediumint unsigned                  not null,
IL          mediumint unsigned                  not null,
Ta          tinyint                             not null,
Tc          tinyint                             not null,
tL          smallint unsigned                   not null,
tN          smallint unsigned                   not null,
PL          tinyint unsigned                    not null,
Hand        tinyint(1)                          not null,
Fire        tinyint(1)                          not null,
Night       tinyint(1)                          not null,
`Load`      tinyint(1)                          not null,
Disch       tinyint(1)                          not null,
OverIL      tinyint(1)                          not null,
ShortL      tinyint(1)                          not null,
ip          int unsigned                        not null,
typeReceipt tinyint(1)                          not null ,
timeReceipt timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
constraint md5receipt
    unique (md5receipt)
);

create index DsNtR
    on data (serialNum, typeReceipt);


create table if not exists dataResponse
(
id              bigint unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
md5receipt      char(32)                            not null,
serialNum       bigint unsigned                     not null,
text            tinytext                            not null,
ip              int unsigned                        not null,
commandResponse char                                not null,
timeReceipt     timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
typeReceipt     tinyint(1)                          not null,
constraint md5receipt
    unique (md5receipt)
)
comment 'ответы устройств';

create index DRsNtR
    on dataResponse (serialNum, typeReceipt);

create table if not exists modemsInfo
(
id                bigint unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
serialNum         bigint(12) unsigned zerofill               null,
idCompany         bigint unsigned                            not null,
nameModem         varchar(20)                                not null,
phoneNumber       char(11)                                   not null,
modeDialog        tinyint(1)       default 1                 not null,
commandStatusGPRS char             default '?'               not null,
region            tinytext                                   null,
city              tinytext                                   null,
street            tinytext                                   null,
structure         tinytext                                   null,
latitude          char(11)                                   null,
longitude         char(11)                                   null,
timeActivation    timestamp                                  null,
timeRegister      timestamp        default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
idGroup           bigint unsigned  default 0                 not null,
idIcon            tinyint unsigned default 0                 not null,
model             tinyint(1)                                 not null,
keyDelete         char(32)                                   null,
endTimeKeyDelete  timestamp                                  null,
commandStatusSMS  char             default '?'               not null,
billingPeriodDay  char(2)          default '01'              not null,
billingPeriodTime time             default '00:00:00'        not null,
identifySerialNum mediumint(6) unsigned zerofill             null,
constraint serialNum
    unique (serialNum)
);

create index MIsNmD
on modemsInfo (serialNum, modeDialog);

create index idCompany_2
on modemsInfo (idCompany);

create index idGroup
on modemsInfo (idGroup);
```

EXPLAIN запроса. Не до конца понял всех тонкостей таблицы которой он дает. Много значений которые по словам авторов плохие(Using where; Using filesort, filtered 100% итд...):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сам запрос.

```
SELECT mI.idGroup, mI.id as idModem , mI.commandStatusGPRS, 
    mI.nameModem, mI.commandStatusSMS,
    mI.phoneNumber, mI.region, mI.city ,mI.street, mI.serialNum,
    mI.timeActivation as timeActivation, mI.structure, mI.model, 
    mI.modeDialog,d.timeReceipt as timeReceiptData , 
    dR.timeReceipt as timeReceiptResponse , d.Hand, d.PL, 
     d.`Load`, d.Mode, d.Disch, d.OverIL, d.ShortL, d.typeReceipt
FROM modemsInfo mI
left outer join data d on d.id = (SELECT MAX(da.id)
                                  FROM data da
                                  WHERE mI.serialNum = da.serialNum 
                                  AND mI.modeDialog=da.typeReceipt)
left outer join dataResponse dR on dR.id = (SELECT MAX(dR.id)
                                            FROM dataResponse dR
                                            WHERE mI.serialNum = 
                                                  dR.serialNum 
                                            AND mI.modeDialog = 
                                                dR.typeReceipt)
WHERE mI.idCompany = :idCompany
order by mI.idGroup DESC
```

Структура таблиц, запрос текстом, текстовые запросы создания таблиц и любую другую инфу доброшу, если нужно.

Comment: Мы не лечим по фотографиям. [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120) Выкладывайте информацию согласно [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: по плану тут тяжелый подзапрос к da таблице, ибо там нет индекса по искомым полям, чтобы ускорилось надо `serialNum, modeDialog` индекс иметь. Но и в целом, там возможно не джойнить надо по условию подзапроса, а заджойнить на проивовдную таблицу с группировкой. Можно еще сделать триггер вставки, чтобы он последнюю запись вообще копировал в доп. таблицу, и ее джойнить и в ней будет только одна запись на девайс.

Comment: @Akina Поправил

Comment: @teran я там отредактировал. Вроде как есть групповые индексы во всех трех таблицах или я что-то не понимаю? С ними быстрей или я неправильно групповые сделал

Comment: Согласен с @teran - избавляйтесь от коррелированных подзапросов и превращайте и в обычные группирующие. Типа `SELECT .. FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2 JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t2 GROUP BY .. ) t21) ON .. LEFT JOIN (t3 JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t3 GROUP BY .. ) t31) ON ..`.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за шаблон! Заняло время чтобы подразобраться с ним) Вроде как на данный момент все получилось. В комментарий получившийся запрос не поместится. Он занимать стал 0.0016с.
Если требуется, добавьте в ответ. Я помечу как ответ на вопрос

Comment: Лучше напишите самоответ - и шаблон, и итоговый запрос, можно даже с пояснениями. И для других полезно, и мож какие баллы капнут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Составил такой запрос по шаблону из комментариев.

```
SELECT  mI.idGroup, mI.id as idModem , mI.commandStatusGPRS, mI.nameModem, mI.commandStatusSMS,
                    mI.phoneNumber, mI.region, mI.city ,mI.street, mI.serialNum,
                    mI.timeActivation as timeActivation, mI.structure, mI.model, mI.modeDialog,
                    d.timeReceipt as timeReceiptData , dR.timeReceipt as timeReceiptResponse , d.Hand, d.PL, d.`Load`, d.Mode, d.Disch,
                    d.OverIL, d.ShortL, d.typeReceipt
            FROM modemsInfo mI
            LEFT JOIN (data d  JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as id, serialNum, typeReceipt FROM data d2 GROUP BY serialNum, typeReceipt) t21 ON d.id = t21.id)
                ON mI.serialNum = d.serialNum  AND mI.modeDialog = d.typeReceipt
            LEFT JOIN (dataResponse dR  JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as id,serialNum, typeReceipt FROM dataResponse dR2 GROUP BY serialNum, typeReceipt) t31 ON dR.id = t31.id)
                ON mI.serialNum = dR.serialNum  AND mI.modeDialog = dR.typeReceipt
            WHERE mI.idCompany = :idCompany
            order by mI.idGroup DESC
```

Скорость выполнения уменьшилась с 1.4с до ~0.0016c
Шаблон:
`SELECT .. FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2 JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t2 GROUP BY .. ) t21) ON .. LEFT JOIN (t3 JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t3 GROUP BY .. ) t31) ON ..`